# Accessing a DynamicResource in code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resources, code-behind

I'm fairly new to WPF and XAML, and I'm getting into the use of Resources.

In a ResourceDictionary, I have defined a SolidColorBrush thus:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ActiveTabBrush" Color="LightBlue" />
```

I use this in the XAML for my form like this:

```
Background="{DynamicResource ActiveTabBrush}"
```

I would also like to be able to access this SolidColorBrush in my C# code-behind, but I am at a loss to how to access such resources from code.

```
SolidColorBrush activeBrush = ?????;
```

Could somebody please tell me how I do this?  I've spent a lot of time searching for the answer, but it's difficult to know what to search for.

Comment: Try `var activeBrush = (SolidColorBrush) FindResource("ActiveTabBrush");` in code-behind.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. 
I had to use:
(SolidColorBrush)Application.Current.FindResource("ActiveTabBrush");
but the principle is the same.

I thought this must have been answered before, but I didn't know what to search for.